# Finding all elements in U(30) that maps to element 7 in U(30)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $\phi$ is a homomorphism from $U\left ( 30 \right )$ to $U\left ( 30 \right )$ and that Ker $\phi =\left \{ 1,11 \right \}$. If $\phi \left ( 7 \right )=7$, find all elements of $U\left ( 30 \right ) $ that maps to 7.

I've found that two elements maps to 7 but wonder if that's all about it.

$\phi\left ( 11 \right )=1 \Rightarrow \phi\left ( 11 \right )\phi\left ( 7 \right )=\phi\left ( 7 \right )=\phi\left ( 77 \right )=7 \Rightarrow \phi\left ( 17 \right )=7$.

The other map is $\phi\left ( 7 \right )=7$ by hypothesis.

Are there any unturned stones?

Comment: Once you know the kernel $K$ and a particular solution $g$, then the general solution is given by $gK$. So you got all the elements. This should remind you of the fact that for linear systems general solution=particular + homogeneous.

Comment: @AnuragA What if you were to want to find the homomorphism map $\phi$?

Comment: @Mathematicing, $U(30)$ has order $8$ but $7$ has order $4$. Therefore, $\phi$ is not determined by $\phi(7)$. You need more information. It happens that $U(30)$ is generated by $7$ and $11$ and so you only need to give $\phi(11)$. But this is a separated question.